# h1, h2, h3 around Microdata markup

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata, html-heading

I'm trying to add Microdata markup (using Schema.org) to a page. At the moment, the code looks like this:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <div class="primary">
        <div itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
            <span itemprop="name">Acme Co</span>
        </div>
        <h4 itemprop="name">Blue Widget</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, what I want to do is change the `h4` from "Blue Widget" to "Acme Co Blue Widget". I already have the company name encapsulated by the `Brand` type so I don't want to repeat it on the page. Here's what I'm thinking.

**Possible solution**

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <h4 class="primary">
        <span itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
            <span itemprop="name">Acme Co</span>
        </span>
        <span itemprop="name">Blue Widget</span>
    </h4>
</div>
```

It's not a question of whether the Microdata/Schema.org markup will be valid (I can test that), but will the header be read by browsers as I want it - "Acme Co Blue Widget"? I'm unsure with all the Schema.org stuff going on.

Comment: Do I see the same code twice?

Comment: No you don't - I said I don't want to repeat it hence the second solution.

Comment: ah! yes, I see the differences now ;) dunno in which timezone you are, but it's monday morning here :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s fine.

The [heading elements `h1`-`h6`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements) can contain [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) (which includes `span`). As `span` elements are meaningless, these `h4` are semantically equivalent:

```html
<h4>Foobar</h4>
```

```html
<h4><span>Fo<span>o</span>bar</span></h4>
```

The Microdata attributes don’t change the HTML semantics.

---

An alternative to your solution would be to use the `meta` element (but there is no need to use this alternative if you are happy with your solution):

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <span itemprop="brand" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Brand">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Acme Co" />
  </span>
  <h4 itemprop="name" class="primary">Acme Co Blue Widget</h4>
</div>
```